# parsing a JSON file with multiple JSONs

Tags: json, parsing, curl, awk, sed

I have a JSON file created as response by running multiple curl statements (GET requests to a service) in parallel.

Now when I try to parse the JSON file using python it fails as the file has multiple JSONs appended

Error:

Error: Parse error on line 1:
...CT_AGGREGATE"}]}]}]}{"serviceResponseTim
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

**Example in the file:**

{"serviceResponseTime":510, ...........
.......:[{"categoryId":28162,"metricValue":97,"days":"NONE","metricMappedType":"PRODUCT_AGGREGATE"**}]}]}]}{"serviceResponseTime":387,**"products":[{"productReferenceId":...................

As you see these are 2 response obtained from 2 curl statements but as I ran them in parallel using xargs, it appended the output in 1 line.

Now my problem is parsing this file.

Can anyone suggest a way to either put the output of curl commands into separate lines in the file.

Or a crude way I thought was if I could extract the part from beginning of the file till "}]}]}]}{", cut from the current file and put it into another file and run the JSON parser on that file which would have just 1 JSON o/p. Repeat this in loop till the original file is empty after we have cut out each of the JSON from it. Now my problem is I am not able to extract from beginning of line to }]}]}]}{.

Also all JSON o/ps are appended in 1 line and are not on separate lines else I would have read line by line.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have this input file:

```
{"name": "foo"}{"name": "bar"}
```

You can use the `jq` command:

```
jq -s . input.file
```

to transfer input.file into:

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo"
  },
  {
    "name": "bar"
  }
]
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I installed jq on my mac and run the command but it says  -sh: jq: command not found